# Is it possible to have compiled .js files alongside their .ts counterparts?

Tags: typescript

Currently, when compiling my project, all `*.js` files end up in a separate `dist/` folder together.

Is there a way to have these files alongside their `*.ts` counterparts instead e.g.,

```
|
- app
  |
   -- index.ts
   -- index.js
   -- db
      |
      -- config.ts
      -- config.js
```

Comment: Isn't this the default behaviour if you don't specify an `out` directory or an `outFile`?

Comment: You're right, just had to remove `"outDir": "dist",` from my `tsconfig.json`. Something I missed!